# WPF Trigger on TextBlock Inlines

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBlock that I want to display a user name, and email like this:

```
Firstname Lastname (Email)
```

However, I don't want to put the (Email) part in if the user doesn't have an email on file.  I would also like to italicize the email.  Normally, I would use a TextBlock and add Runs in for the various parts of the text, but I can't find a way to dynamically change a TextBlock's inlines from XAML.

I've tried this:

```
<TextBlock.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasEmail}" Value="True">

  <Setter Property="Inlines" TargetName="contactTagNameEmailTextBlock">
    <Setter.Value>
     <Run Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}" />
     <Run Text="{Binding Path=Lastname}" />
     <Run Text="(" />
     <Run Text="{Binding Path=Email}" />
     <Run Text=")" />
  </Setter.Value>

</Setter>
</DataTrigger>
</TextBlock.Triggers>
```

But VS complains that the value is set more than once (due to the multiple Run's).  How can I get around this?  Alternatively, it would be really convenient if I could set a binding on a whole FrameworkElement.  For example, if I could just put a placeholder in my Grid where I want to put a custom control I construct in code behind on this bound object, that would be the best.

Thanks.

Comment: Tangential: you can probably do `<Run Text="{Binding Path=Email, StringFormat='({0})'}" />` instead of using 3 runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like that should work :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibility x:Key="visibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}" />
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Lastname}" />
    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding HasEmail, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
        <Run Text="(" />
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Email}" />
        <Run Text=")" />
    </TextBlock>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This works, thanks!  WPF is definitely a different way of doing things.

Comment: note: you can put the TextBlock in an <InlineUIContainer> and then change the baseline alignment if needed. Blend will do this automatically (maybe VS too, but not sure)

Comment: Voted down because this is not the proper way to do this. This breaks the layout engine's ability to determine metrics for things like TextTrimming, etc. It may look correct, but you'll see problems.

Comment: @MarqueIV, what exactly breaks it? And what's the correct way according to you?

Comment: As I stated above, things like TextTrimming break.  You can see this using this template in a ListBox, seetting its TextTrimming property to CharacterEllipses, then disabling the ListBox's horizontal scrollbar. Run and make the width smaller.  The layout gets mangled.  It's worse when using it in a DockPanel as things start to overlap and slide under other areas.  I've added an answer demonstrating the correct way to use runs that change via a trigger.

Answer (score 4):

Look into Multibinding and StringFormat

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
      <Binding Path="LastName" />
      <Binding Path="FirstName" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

You should be able to hide the () if email isn't there.

Comment: I don't know how to hide part of a format string if one of the parameters is empty.  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer here that says to nest TextBlock elements will cause issues with layout.  For instance, the outer TextBlock will no longer properly respect TextTrimming settings.

Here's a better approach which gives you the flexibility of runs set via a trigger* which still allow proper layout.

> Note: I added the formatting properties (Foreground, Bold) to show why you would use Runs here instead of a simple multi-binding.  Using Runs (or any inlines) allows you to format the text of a TextBlock, but still have it respect layout (i.e. TextTrimming works as expected, etc.)

```
<ContentControl x:Name="TextBlockPresenter">
    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}" />
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Lastname}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Run Text="(" Foreground="Gray" />
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Email}" Foreground="Gray" />
        <Run Text=")" Foreground="Gray" />
    </TextBlock>
</ContentControl>

[SomeTriggerArea]

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasEmail}" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="TextBlockPresenter" Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}" />
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Lastname}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>

[/SomeTriggerArea]
```

** Technically you aren't setting the runs via a trigger.  You're setting an entirely new template which has a TextBox that has the proper runs defined.*

> It's also a good idea to set IsHitTestVisible to False if you're using Runs like this in a control which you may want to respond to mouse hits, then walk the visual tree (i.e. a TreeView where you listen to a right mouse-down, walk the tree to find the TreeViewItem and set IsSelected to true.) This is because the runs will respond to the mouse, but they aren't a FrameworkElement so when you call VisualTreeHelper.GetParent using e.OriginalSource, you'll get an exception.  Simply disabling the TextBlock from participating in the mouse events avoids that.